# Why would a child process call getppid()? What can the PID of the Parent be used for?

Tags: linux, process, fork

When calling `fork()` the PID of the parent is saved in the child's PCB. In which case would it be useful for the child to know its parent's PID?

Comment: If he wants to send a signal to the parent process. Or just to check if the parent is still alive.

Comment: @KamilCuk Got you, by 2 seconds 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A process may wish to know if it was started by the `init` process at system startup, for example, and modify its behaviour accordingly.

Or, it may wish to communicate with its parent, say, to indicate something is complete, by sending a signal.